# How do I install Ubuntu when ACPI errors are being shown?

Tags: dual-boot, acpi, amd-processor

While installing Ubuntu on my Acer nitro an515-42 with AMD processor ACPI error is occurring. How to overcome this?

Errors that are occurring during installation:

```
ACPI error : [MACO] namespace failure, AE_ALREADY_EXIST
....
....
[Firmware Bug] : AMD Vi :IOAPIC [4] not in IVRIS  table
[Firmware Bug] : AMD Vi :IOAPIC [5] not in IVRIS  table
[Firmware Bug] : AMD Vi : No southbridge IOAPIC found
```

Comment: Does the errors prevent the installation to finish?

Comment: Yes, installation is not starting